# Is it possible to develop a .NET library with optional reference/dependency and still benefit from IntelliSense/typing?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, shared-libraries, assemblies

Let's say I want to write a library and it should invoke `OptionalLibClass.Run()` if such method is available. However the assembly is big (like `SkiaSharp`) so I do not want to include it with my library, in case the end developer only need other features.

I know it's possible to use `System.Reflection` but you lose the benefit of Intellisense and static typing as well as getting a performance hit (though pretty minor IMO, usually it's not a problem).

**Expectation:**

- Add `OptionalLib` as a reference. Still it should be optional: user should not have to install `OptionalLib` if they install `MyLib` from Nuget for example.
- Write the following code in the library:

```cs
using OptionalLib; // .NET should be able to see this namespace
// ...

if (OptionalLibAvailable()) // How to implement OptionalLibAvailable?
{
    OptionalLibClass.Run() // IntelliSense should be able to show me OptionalLibClass
}
```

- End user (developer) doesn't need to do anything beside referring to `OptionalLib` if they want to.

Note that there may be multiple optional libs.

**Possible Workaround:**

While typing the questions, I thought of a few solutions though they are not as simple as I would like:

- Make an interface `IOptionalRun` for example. However, end user has to provide their own implementation.
- Following above workaround, add a separate `MyLib` (without `OptionalLib`) and `MyLib.OptionalLib` (with `OptionalLib`) that provides an `IOptionalRun` implementation. I think this is the best workaround so far and the closest to my expectation but we still need 2 separate assemblies and the user has to register the interface somehow. *This workaround has a problem when there are multiple optional libraries* and we want users to have any of their combinations (for example: do A if A is available, B if B is available but C if both A and B are available)
- Using `dynamic`: the worst workaround IMO. Technically a shorter `System.Reflection` solution but still have all its problem.

**EDIT:** After reading my question again, turn out a solution will *probably* be the answer to: how to pack/create a Nuget package for a project that contains `OptionalLib` but it should not be in the dependency list (and don't pack that dll when packing the Nuget package). `OptionalLibAvailable` can just be a Reflection call to see if `OptionalLib` assembly is loaded in the current `AppDomain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the properties of that big assembly reference, in the properties window, there is a property **Private Assets**, set its value to **All**, then repack your library, you will find that reference has gone from the .nuspec file.

Comment: Private Assets is going to strip out the dependency from the release and remove the type information that isn't explicitly included.  This won't provide end users with any intellisense.

Comment: @AdamCohen, the OP said: _"End user (developer) doesn't need to do anything beside referring to OptionalLib if they want to."_

Comment: I misread the question and thought the OP wanted to expose intellisense to end user w/o the weight of the large package.  My fault - sorry.

Comment: Also note that to prevent the AssemblyNot Found exception, make sure the code that accesses the optional assembly is in a separate method (not in the same method with the `if` for example).